# Fastest way of updating a Python list based on indices

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, vectorization

I have a Python dictionary like this -

```
my_dict = {'Names':['Tom', 'Mariam', 'Lata', 'Tina', 'Abin'], 
           'Attendance':[False, False, False, False, False]}
```

I also have a Python list of flags for which indices need to changed to True in `my_dict['Attendance']` -

```
flag_list = [0, 2, 3]
```

Based on the `flag_list`, `my_dict` needs to be changed to -

```
my_dict = {'Names':['Tom', 'Mariam', 'Lata', 'Tina', 'Abin'], 
           'Attendance':[True, False, True, True, False]}
```

What would be the fastest way of achieving this? Can it be done without a loop? Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a loop

```
for index in flag_list:
    my_dict['Attendance'][index] = True
```

A micro optimization would be to fetch the list from the dict only once:

```
attendance_list = my_dict['Attendance']
for index in flag_list:
    attendance_list[index] = True
```

But unless `flag_list` is thousands elements long I wouldn't worry about it.

### Using vectorization

If you are willing to take advantage of vectorization you can use a [numpy](https://numpy.org/install/) array:

```
import numpy as np

my_dict = {'Names':['Tom', 'Mariam', 'Lata', 'Tina', 'Abin'],
           'Attendance': np.array([False, False, False, False, False])}
flag_list = [0, 2, 3]
my_dict['Attendance'][flag_list] = True
```

But again, unless your data is **very** big I wouldn't worry about optimizing this piece of code very much.

## Example timings

```
import random

from timeit import Timer

import numpy as np


ATTENDANCE_LIST_SIZE = 100000
FLAG_LIST_SIZE = 60000

dict_with_numpy = {'Attendance': np.random.choice([False, True], 
                                 ATTENDANCE_LIST_SIZE)}
dict_without_numpy = {'Attendance': random.choices([False, True], 
                                    k=ATTENDANCE_LIST_SIZE)}
flag_list = random.choices(range(ATTENDANCE_LIST_SIZE), k=FLAG_LIST_SIZE)


def using_numpy():
    dict_with_numpy['Attendance'][flag_list] = True


def no_numpy_pre_fetching_list():
    attendance_list = dict_without_numpy['Attendance']
    for index in flag_list:
        attendance_list[index] = True


def no_numpy():
    for index in flag_list:
        dict_without_numpy['Attendance'][index] = True


print(f'no_numpy\t\t\t\t\t\t{min(Timer(no_numpy).repeat(3, 3))}')
print(f'no_numpy_pre_fetching_list\t\t{min(Timer(no_numpy_pre_fetching_list).repeat(3, 3))}')
print(f'using_numpy\t\t\t\t\t\t{min(Timer(using_numpy).repeat(3, 3))}')
```

For this amount of data, the output is (on my machine)

```
no_numpy                        0.009737916999999985
no_numpy_pre_fetching_list      0.0048406370000000365
using_numpy                     0.009164470000000036
```

So using vectorization **for this data** is **not** the most efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Yes, currently I am using numpy. I guess, my list would be around 50 elements long.

Comment: This is amazing. no_numpy_pre_fetching_list() is taking half the time taken by numpy. Thank you for demonstrating this!